# Is there a possibility to set the 0,0 coordinate on android beneath the toolbar or make the toolbar not overlappable?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have the following problem:
On my android program I can create imageViews and buttons via a click on a button. These new buttons and imageViews get created at the top left corner at the 0,0 coordinate. The problem is now that I included a toolbar now instead of the standard ActionBar. When my buttons and imageViews are created now, they overlapped by the toolbar. I need a possibility to either change the coordinate system beneath the toolbar or simply make the toolbar not overlappable.
I already tried working with different layouts, like including the toolbar in a Linear Layout, the main layout beneath it etc. but I found nothing that works!

I ask for help, thank you very much!

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="bbb"
        android:text="@string/ccc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="eee"
        android:text="@string/fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ggg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hhh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="iii"
        android:text="@string/jjj"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kkk"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="mmm"
        android:text="@string/ooo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nnn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ppp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="validate"
        android:text="@string/qqq"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rrr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sss"
        android:text="@string/ttt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/uuu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vvv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="www"
        android:text="@string/button_share"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/xxx"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

MainActivity.java
Here I also added the toolbar in replacement for the ActionBar

```
       Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Edit:
MainActivity.xml with the ?android attribute which handels the problem visually but doesn't solve the problem at all.

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="bbb"
        android:text="@string/ccc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="eee"
        android:text="@string/fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ggg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hhh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="iii"
        android:text="@string/jjj"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kkk"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="mmm"
        android:text="@string/ooo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nnn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ppp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="validate"
        android:text="@string/qqq"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rrr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sss"
        android:text="@string/ttt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/uuu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vvv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="www"
        android:text="@string/button_share"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/xxx"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the `.xml` where you created the toolbar?

Comment: I edited my post :)

Comment: Set your constraint's to be below the toolbar, currently they are constrained to the parent which is the whole screen so the toolbar is going to show ontop of everything

Comment: I actually tried it already but I think the problem is, that even if I set e.g. the marginTop to the Bottom of the toolbar, I still need the match parent attribute. I solved it with the ?android:attr/actionBarSize, but the problem was the same. MAybe the match parent is the problem, but I don't know how to overcome this.

Comment: constraining to the parent top is the problem because the toolbar is also in that spot. `actionBarSize` will "solve" the problem visually but its still technically under the toolbar still

Comment: Exactly this is my problem which I have nop idea how to overcome. I will edit and post the version with the ?android attribute. I have no ideas anymore.

Comment: When I include the toolbar into a ConstraintLayout e.g. as well, the buttons and images are reated above the toolbar, which is again not what I need.

Comment: I dont have an editor in front of me but I believe the issue is this `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` it should be `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOff="@+id/toolbar"` notice its now constrained to the bottom of the toolbar

Comment: ```app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"``` can't be the problem here because this attribute is only included for the buttons which I use to create imageViews and buttons. But even when I use ```app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOff="@+id/toolbar"``` in the ConstraintLayout which I can create for the view beneath the toolbar, it is not working :(

Comment: Oh I just noticed you have two constraint layouts in this file, thats also part of the problem. I will give you a solution shortly

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.xml` of toolbar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="your path to the activity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
             android:elevation="4dp"
             android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
             app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/your_xml_for_activity_the_one_with_buttons" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in `MainActivity.java` use:
`setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);`

Like this you will create the toolbar, and will use the content of the buttons `xml` to be displayed under it.

Comment: I am getting the following error using this xml (of course with the needed changed):
AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay (aka com.example.projectname:style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay) not found.

I also deleted the toolbar include in the mainactivity.xml

Comment: Ah right, I gave you a sample from an own project. Add in `style.xml` the following: `<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />`

Comment: This fixed the problem!
But now it seems to be a new problem when starting the app ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectname/com.example.projectname.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Add in the `build:gradle (Module:app)` the following `dependency` : `implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'` and sync.

Comment: And next one, I remember that I once had a problem like that which kept unsolved:
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
 is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

Comment: Try to change `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: This isnt the greatest of solutions as now you have to create a new toolbar layout for each new screen you want a toolbar since you are creating a hard dependency on this one toolbar to a specific layout.

Comment: Same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can get you on your way as I dont know what the layout is you are trying to accomplish but this layout stacks the buttons starting below the toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/aaa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aaa"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/hhh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ddd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/lll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/hhh"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/ppp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lll"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/rrr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ppp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/vvv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rrr"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I think I get now the confusion from the comments above. The problem are not the buttons I already have there. These buttons are constrained to my bottom right corner. I only use them for actions. The problem are the buttons and imageViews I create with these functions. For example sth. like "create imageView". This imageView will appear at coordinates 0,0 and are overlapped from my toolbar. So ```app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"``` and ```app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"``` are not needed here for my buttons, which are there already.

Comment: One solution could be to set the constraints of every imageView and button dynamically in code at their creation, but of course it would be better to simply constrain the views to do that.